# Not Able to debug my application after build with maven

Tags: maven-3, jboss7.x

I've build my web project with maven3 and then deployed on jboss, m able to access the application but when I trying to debug the source code, it is showing **source not found.** Is there any way to debug the source code after maven build and deployment??

Answer (score 0):

Have you added below options in standalone.conf file to enable application debugging

```
-Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8787,server=y,suspend=y
```

Comment: without maven it is working fine only after maven build if m running server in debug mode it is saying "Source not found"

Comment: able to solve this problem by converting my simple "maven project" to " facet project ". By right click on my maven proejct-->configure-->convert to facet project.Now m successfully able to debug my application after build it with maven and deploy on jboss 7.1..!!!!!!!!!!!